# Some clarification on using selectList please?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am trying to populate a SelectList:

```
new SelectList(db.StdOrgUser, "Id", "LastName", stdlibraryitem.StdOrgUserId);
```

The above is the straightforward approach in that "LastName" comes from the StdOrgUser table. However "StdOrgUser" is linked to "Aspnet_Membership" and therefore to "Aspnet_Users".

```
StdOrgUser (*-1) Aspnet_Membership (0..1 - 1) Aspnet_Users
```

I would like to access the "username" as stored in  "Aspnet_Users" in the SelectList as opposed to "LastName". Is this possible and how?

Many thanks.

Comment: First off, it looks like you are accessing your DbContext directly in the View. This is a bad practice. You should be creating a View Model POCO class and your Razor View should be strongly typed to that View Model class. What you need to do is build a LINQ query that joins the StdOrgUser and aspnet_users tables and return the username.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually this selectList is being populated in the controller, and passed back via ViewBag. Assume I do have a "UsernameList" from a LINQ query. How should I change the "SelectList" statement to incorporate this. Obviously I am trying to populate "StdOrgUser", but use the "UserNameList" just for display reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use view bag, rather pass your data using a view model.  Don't pass in your domain model, use a view model.

Lets start with your action method.  Lets call it `YourActionMethod`. It creates an instance of your view model and populates the user list with your users.  How you populate your users in the sevice layer depends entirely up to you.

```
public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
     YourViewModel viewModel = new YourViewModel
     {
          Users = userService.FindAll()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Your view model can look like this (partial):

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public int UserId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Create a domain model to represent your users. Your user domain model could look something like this:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public string UserName { get; set; }

     public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Your view (page) will receive your view model:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Users.YourViewModel
```

And you drop down HTML markup will look like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.UserId,
     new SelectList(Model.Users, "Id", "UserName", Model.UserId),
     "-- Select --"
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserId)
```

Comment: Thank you for this very instructive response.